# Calculating the supremum distance

Tags: data-mining

In this example I would like to figure out how to calculate the supremum distance. Given the example shown below

[image]

I would like to know what f and h represent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to this [resource](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/euclidean-distance).

$h$ is a real number such that $h \ge 1$. It represents the Manhattan Distance when $h = 1$ (i.e., L1 norm) and Euclidean Distance when $h = 2$ (i.e., L2 norm). We find the attribute $f$ that gives the maximum difference in values between the two objects.